# How to compute $\int_{I\times I} f d\lambda \times d\mu$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\lambda$ be Lebesgue measure and $\mu$ be counting measure both regarded as Borel measures on $I=\left[0,1\right] $. Let $\Delta$ be the diagonal in $I\times I:\Delta=\left\{\left(x,y\right) | x=y\right\} $. Let $f$ be a characteristic function of $\Delta$.

I don't know how to compute  $\int_{I\times I}fd\lambda \times d\mu$. This is part of a question:

$(a)$ Compute the integrals:$\int_{I}\left(\int_{I}fd\lambda\right)d\mu$ , $\int_{I}\left(\int_{I}fd\mu\right)d\lambda$ and $\int_{I\times I}fd\lambda \times d\mu$

$(b)$ Why the result above does contradict Fubini theorem.

From the definition I know that:$\int_{I}\left(\int_{I}fd\lambda\right)d\mu$=$0$ and  $\int_{I}\left(\int_{I}fd\mu\right)d\lambda$=$1$. And since counting measure is not $\sigma$-finite which is why two results above we've calculated does not contradict Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: What is the counting measure on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @air All subsets are measurable, and a singleton has measure $1?$

Comment: @awllower Makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The measure of the diagonal of a unit square in an alternative measure.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556473/the-measure-of-the-diagonal-of-a-unit-square-in-an-alternative-measure)